# Error when Copying large datasets (500k records) between sheets using rng.value=rng.value method

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to optimally copy large datasets (500k records) from one workbook to other. I am using the following line of code:

```
Sheet13.Range("A2:D" & last).Value2 = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:D" & last).Value2
```

I tried to debug and Now what happens it is copying all the records all right till it finds a cell with the following value starting with "=":
e.g., one of the cell had value "=Abc  dc"

I want to do the copy in an optimal way and looping to check and remove = doesn't look right.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just copy the entire worksheet from one workbook to another? If there are columns after D, then you could always delete them in the copy.

Comment: try `Sheet13.Range("A2:D" & last).copy` and in a new line `OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:D" & last).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: @Applecore Copying the entire worksheet will change the Sheet name. I am referencing Sheets in the VBA logic in various functions.

Comment: @MG92 That works, but found online that rng.value=rng.value copy paste method is supposed to be the fastest. So, I was trying to get this work but it throws "application undefined error" and stop cpying from the place where it encountered string string starting with =

Comment: @RohitKumar you can then change the name of the sheet in the other workbook when you have copied it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

As copying the worksheet between workbooks doesn't work, you can also copy columns between two workbooks:

```
Workbooks("steer.xlsm").Worksheets("Report2").Range("A:D").Copy Workbooks("rsformat.xlsx").Worksheets("test2").Range("A:D")
```

This will preserve anything in column E onwards in the destination worksheet, and should be faster than loading data into an array.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks. I had used this earlier but was looking for the most optimal way to copy considering both speed and Memory issues. rng.value method was recommended everywhere online..But couldn;t make that to work for some strings ..those starting with "=". So, I am going ahead with this alternate solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not try use an array?

```vb
    Dim myArray() as Variant

    myArray = Sheet13.Range("A2:D" & last).Value

    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A2").Resize(UBound(myArray,1), UBound(myArray,2)).Value = myArray
```

Comment: Thanks , I hadnt considered using array. This does look the fastest method. Only that .value part still throws error because it finds a cell with string starting with "=".

Comment: That should not throw an error - I have just tested it.

Comment: Not sure what is the issue then. The exact string where it shows error is "=ØIÜ 1/2 Price Tuesday <Ø9ß  Special" . Till this cell it copies all right, but stops right here with here..with pretty generic - "Application defined or object defined error"

Answer (score -1):

Just use `Worksheet.Copy` and then rename the worksheet:

```
Sub sCopySheet(wsSource As Worksheet, strName As String)
    wsSource.Select
    wsSource.Copy Before:=Workbooks("rsFormat.xlsx").Sheets(1)
    Workbooks("rsFormat.xlsx").Sheets(1).Name = strName
End Sub

Sub sTestCopy()
    Call sCopySheet(Worksheets("20Apr'20"), "test2")
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mention before. I have some formulae after column D in the destination worksheet. That's another reason why copying the entire worksheet will not work. :)

Comment: Oh well :( Sorry it didn't help